# Calling a function in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I had some code similar to this, how would I go about calling the `getUserName()` function inside the `ng-repeat`. I attempted to do it earlier and it worked, however, it no longer functions.

```
 var user_reviews = [{
     user: {
         name: "John Doe"
     },
     review: {
         item: "Shure SE215"
     }
 }]

 var app = angular.module("ExApp", []);
 app.controller("TestController", function($scope) {
     $scope.reviews = user_reviews;
     $scope.getUserName = function() {
         return $scope.user.name;
     }
 });
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
  <div ng-repeat="review in reviews">
    <p>{{review.getUserName()}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: y dont u directly take the name instead calling function  <p>{{review.user.name}}</p>

Comment: Im trying to call a function because I need to do some string manipulation inside the function. And @IsmailRBOUH that doesn't work, I have tried that already.

Comment: If you don't need this as function, you shall not use function.

Comment: What version of Angular do you use?

Comment: {{getUserName(review)}}
...
 $scope.getUserName = function(review){
        return review.user.name; 
      }

Comment: @PatrykPerduta I am using Angular 1.5.6

Comment: @iiro That works! Thank you! But out of curiosity, why doesn't my way work? with ng-repeat, does it create a new scope that isn't the correct one?

Comment: your review-variable doesn't have a function called getUserName. As i remember ng-repeat creates a child scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming scope.getUserName() isn't as trivial as it is in your example, you can do this instead.

```
    // Pass the `review` object as argument
    $scope.getUserName = function(review){
        return review.user.name; // get the user name from it
    }
```

HTML, pass `review` as parameter

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
  <div ng-repeat="review in reviews">
    <p>{{getUserName(review)}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the index from ng-repeat and return the user.name relevant to that index

```
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
      <div ng-repeat="review in reviews">
        <p>{{getUserName($index)}}</p>
      </div>
    </div> 

  var app = angular.module("ExApp", []); 
    app.controller("TestController", function($scope){
      $scope.reviews = user_reviews; 
      $scope.getUserName = function(index){
        return $scope.reviews[index].user.name; 
      }
    });
```

but if you are using function for this senario only i prefer do it without the function like this

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
          <div ng-repeat="review in reviews">
            <p>{{review.user.name}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//You can directly access the username 
    <div ng-controller="TestController">
      <div ng-repeat="review in reviews">
        <p>{{review.user.name}}</p>
      </div>
    </div> 

//or You can pass the review as parameter and return username from that function.
    //HTML
    <div ng-controller="TestController">
      <div ng-repeat="review in reviews">
        <p>{{getUserName(review)}}</p>
      </div>
    </div> 
    //JS
    $scope.getUserName = function(review){
        return review.user.name; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to this.

```
<div ng-controller="TestController"><div ng-repeat="review in reviews">
<p ng-repeat="userName in review.getUserName(review.name)">{{userName.name}}</p></div></div>

var user_reviews = [
  {
    user:{
      name: "John Doe"
    }, 
    review:{
      item: "Shure SE215"
    } 
  } 
]

var app = angular.module("ExApp", []); 
app.controller("TestController", function($scope){
  $scope.reviews = user_reviews; 
  $scope.getUserName = function(userName){
    return $scope.user.name; 
  }
});
```